# Why is recursion faster than iteration in JS?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've been doing JS problems on LeetCode and noticed that the recursive solutions run faster than the iterative solutions in almost every case (ex. DFS with a stack vs recursion).

I looked online and found a couple of blog posts that came to similar conclusions around performance.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/performance-of-recursion-vs-loop-using-javascript

The Oreily book, like most formal material on the subject, states that iteration is more performant because of the "lower overhead" which I understand but then why isn't that the case in practice?
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-javascript/9781449382308/ch04.html

I do see that recursion can fail at particularly large stack sizes but it always seems to be more performant than iteration. What's going on? I saw that TCO hasn't been implemented in JS so I'm very confused.

Comment: The article you show might not show accurate measurements. As far as I can see, it just runs each once. It doesn't seem like it's giving the JIT enough time to "warm up" and accurately measure the iterative solution. Also, the function is called *once*, for better accuracy, you need to run the function under test multiple times. Similarly, your findings are inconclusive because we don't even know if you're comparing the two fairly. Perhaps the JIT is not able to optimise the loop as much due to different semantics.

Comment: DFS doesn't use TCO anyway, it does require a stack

Comment: Did you run the "benchmarks" from that first article yourself? For larger values of `n` (where the stack size would be substantial), the iterative approach *does* win for me. Also you should remove the `console.log` call, which does have considerable overhead, especially on the first call.

Comment: Iteration is generally faster than recursion but it depends. Are you constantly appending to an array in the iteration? Doing that causes the interpreter to allocate memory from heap. Your recursive function may turn out to not constantly be carving out the heap. Local variables and parameters take memory from the stack instead and there may be a slight speed advantage with that

Comment: It's important to know the distinction between **process** and a **procedure** (function). A recursive function can evolve a recursive process, an exponential process, _or_ an iterative process. Similarly, a non-recursive function can evolve an iterative process (think simple `for` loop) or an exponential process (think something like Ackerman function).

Answer (score 2):

Well, to understand recursion over iteration (or vice versa), we need to understand how both technique works.

What is recursion?

1. It's function calling it self. so number of calls take place, number of times the properties of function (which includes variables, data-structures, sub-functions that the main function uses, will recreate over and over again). and at the end, compiler or (JIT in case of JavaScript) must face some overheads.
2. And the process will continue until/unless base case have found, in this case all overheads during recursion will release.
3. In case, if base-case not found/matched all the stack-frame which was allocated for this particular function will be exhausted, and we will get some thing like: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`

What is Iteration?

1. As the name suggest, it's a repetitive instruction which will perform some operation given by the coder.
2. In compare to Recursion, no other stack-frame will be used without main-stack-frame. and all the properties of the function will be reinitialised with new value over and over again.

Based on the comparison i have made, you can clearly get an idea, which is more and which is less efficient to Compiler or to JIT. (and it is generalised to every language you will work on).

Now coming to the performance, the article link which you provided clearly not showing accurate measurements of all the scenarios. The time to execute a function clearly and mainly depends on the number of instruction the function performs.

Looking at the following snippets you can re-think about the conclusion you have so far:

```js
function nthFibo(a){
    if(a <= 2){
        return a;
    }else{
        return nthFibo(a-1)+nthFibo(a-2);
    }
   }


console.time("looping #1");  
console.log(nthFibo(45));
console.timeEnd("looping #1");
```

and also check the time required for iteration, which will give you same output as recursion gave:

```js
function nthFiboIterative(a){
    var first = 0, second = 1;
    var result = 0;
    var i = 1;
    while(i ++ <= a){
        result = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = result;
    }
    return result;
}

console.time("looping #2");  
console.log(nthFiboIterative(45));
console.timeEnd("looping #2");
```

But this is not a fair test as our first program creates an exponential process that we compare to a linear process in the second program. Let's see a recursive `nthFibo` that evolves a linear iterative process -

```js
function nthFibo (a, x = 1, y = 1)
{ if (a == 0)
    return x;
  else
    return nthFibo(a - 1, y, x + y)
}

console.time("looping #3");  
console.log(nthFibo(45));
console.timeEnd("looping #3");
```

It's important to know the distinction between **process** and a **procedure** (function). A recursive function can evolve a recursive process, an exponential process, or an iterative process. Similarly, a non-recursive function can evolve an iterative process (think simple for loop) or an exponential process (think something like Ackerman function).

Comment: This is a bad example because you compare an exponential process to a an iterative one. I added a `looping #3` example that shows recursion can compute `fib(45)` in the same time as `looping #2`. To get better metrics out of this you'll need to write better test functions and use a better benchmarking tool.

Comment: but @Thankyou even though you are calling recursively in `looping #3`, it's still in behaving in iterative manner. in that case try to use value some greater for example, instead of 45 use 80 you can see the difference . have a good night.

Comment: Papai that is exactly the point. A recursive function can evolve a linear iterative process (see also [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)). However a recursive function, even if an iterative one, will _always_ be slower (even if by a negligible amount) than a `for` or `while` loop because it has frame create/destroy overhead and will always be limited by the stack size. `for` and `while` do not have this overhead nor limitation.

Comment: yes absolutely, agreed! and accepting the fact in my original answer i gave an wrong (in context) example, i should have gave an example of iterative-recursive to make more sense. a huge thanks to you!

Comment: appreciate the discussion thank you :D

Comment: `looping #3` (linear recursion, 0.370ms) outperforms `looping #2` (iterative, 0.390ms). I'm not seeing "a recursive function, even if an iterative one, will always be slower." Are you saying this is because there are fewer instructions in the function than compared to the loop?